# Get JWT Tokens in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, oauth, token

There is a function in Outlook API called  getCallbackTokenAsync([options], callback);

Office.context.mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync
How can I get such function in SharePoint Online? Is there an analog for it?

I've searched over the Internet and found that there's no such a function.

But can anyone suggest how to get JWT REST tokens?

Thank you!